# Three logical operators in R

Tags: r, if-statement, logical-operators

I would like to check three logical operators in R in the same line. That is I want Y1 to become 1 if x1 **or** x3 are smaller than 0.05 **or** x2 is smaller than 0.1

```
if (x1 <0.05 | x2 < 0.1 | x3 <0.05) {  
    Y1 <- 1 
  }
```

However, R gives me the following error message:

```
## Warning in if (x1 < 0.05 | x2 < 0.1 | x3 < 0.05) {: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Why does R give me an error message? And if it is a problem how can I solve this without using two if-statements?

Comment: x1, x2 and x3 are probably vectors of length > 1 right? You  should probably use the `ifelse()` function which is vectorized.

Comment: Please make the error reprodrucible by providing an example of `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and `y1`.

Comment: what should Y1 be if the cond is not met.

Answer (score 1):

The `ifelse()` function is what you are looking for probably

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- runif(1000, 0,1)
x2 <- runif(1000, 0,1)
x3 <- runif(1000, 0,1)

y1 <- ifelse(x1 <0.05 | x2 < 0.1 | x3 <0.05, 1, NA)
y1[1:20]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA  1 NA  1 NA  1 NA NA  1 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Y1 <- as.numeric(x1 <0.05 | x2 < 0.1 | x3 <0.05)
```

Wrapping your statement with `as.numeric` returns a `1` if `TRUE` and a `0` if `FALSE`